# iPhone resizing subviews and origin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, scale

If I scale subviews in a uiview, do those subviews respect the x,y they were originally drawn at? i.e if i have a view with 2 subviews , one at 50 and one at 60 and i increase the size of parent view by 3, will the subviews now draw at 150 and the other one at 180?

Comment: do you realise that trying it would've been quicker than posting this question here?

Comment: Tried and did not work, so not sure if that is supposed to work or am doing something wrong.

Comment: I think you need to post code also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parent will not automaticly scale the size of its childrens subviews.
But when u want a zoom function with subviews on them that will scale with the parent it is quite possible to do so.

But without a proper example of what you want exactly it's impossible to give a proper answer